# FeatureUnion with different feature dimensions

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I want to classify some sentences with sklearn. The sentences are stored in a Pandas DataFrame.

To begin, I want to use the length of the sentence and it's TF-IDF vectors as a feature, so I created this pipeline:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
        ('meta', Pipeline([
            ('length', LengthAnalyzer())
        ])),
        ('bag-of-words', Pipeline([
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer())
        ]))
    ])),
    ('model', LogisticRegression())
```

where the LengthAnalyzer is a custom `TransformerMixin`with:

```
    def transform(self, documents):
        for document in documents:
            yield len(document)
```

So, LengthAnalyzer returns a number (1 dimension) while TfidfVectorizer returns a n-dimensional list.

When I try to run this, I get

```
ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,1].shape[0] == 494, expected 1.
```

What has to be done to make this feature combination work?

Comment: Convert that one number to a 2-d array of shape [1,1]

Comment: Like np.array(len(document)).reshape(-1,1)? Same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the problem is originating from the `yield` used in the transform(). Maybe due to `yield` the number of rows reported to the `scipy hstack` method is 1 instead of actual number of samples in `documents`.

There should be 494 rows (samples) in your data which is coming correct from `TfidfVectorizer` but `LengthAnalyzer` is only reporting a single row. Hence the error.

If you can change it to

`return np.array([len(document) for document in documents]).reshape(-1,1)`

then the pipeline fits successfully.

Note:
I tried finding any related issue on [scikit-learn github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues) but was unsuccessful. You can post this issue there to get some real feedback for the usage.